# Running tlbimp.exe command in Windows 10 doesn't generate a new ADODB.dll anymore

Tags: c#, .net, delphi, com, windows-10

I'm trying to update our build environment for our Enterprise application to Windows 10.

Our Enterprise application was originally developed in Delphi, but we have migrated *most* of our code base to C#/.NET.

As such part of the build process is to run tlbimp.exe to convert some Delphi COM type library into assemblies in the .NET CLR.

The build process is working fine in Windows Server 2008 R2, but as we upgrade our environment to Windows 10 it breaks.

The reason is that previously when we run tlbimp.exe against a particular tlb, in additions to the .NET assembly, tlbimp.exe will also generate an ADODB.dll assembly in Windows Server 2008 R2 but not in Windows 10.

Thus, the build breaks because of the missing ADODB.dll.

I am not familiar with Delphi or COM object, but I believe ADODB.dll is a Microsoft Visual Studio .NET assembly for the Windows OS.

**My question is: Shouldn't ADODB.dll come with either Visual Studio or Windows OS?**

Why would tlbimp.exe generate a new ADODB.dll when importing a COM type library?

In addition, why wouldn't it generate the file again when running the same tlbimp.exe in Windows 10?

Comment: ADODB.dll comes with Visual Studio. Check this out: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-1.1/aa720078(v=vs.71). I have a Windows 10 machine with Visual Studio 2017 only, and it's in fact present in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft.NET\Primary Interop Assemblies`. Since it's a 64-bit machine it's only there, not in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft.NET\Primary Interop Assemblies`

Comment: Try to set the target platform of the project to x86 (or Win32), or run tlbimp.exe in the environment of x64_x86 Cross Tools Command Prompt or x86 Native Tools Command Prompt.